# How to keep some element on page when I filter?

Tags: jquery, filter

I found a nice filter and used it on my little home-work.
I would like to keep the h2 element visible during filtering, if its not empty. Thought it would be possible to use multiple data-id, but it did not work for me. I am curious what solutions others might have for me.

---

**EDIT**: I would like to change question a little bit. There shouldnt be empty header when its filtered.

So possibly I am looking for the way to toggle element h2 ->".hide" when the next elements with data-pobocka="XY" are empty.

[all the code](https://www.cumclavi.cz/betaFiltracniTabulka.html)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
              var $lectures = $('.beseda'),
                $filters = $("#filters input[type='checkbox']"),
                product_filter = new ListOfLecturesFilter($lectures, $filters);
              product_filter.init();
              
              });
              
              function ListOfLecturesFilter(lectures, filters) {
              var _this = this;
              
              this.init = function() {
                this.lectures = lectures;
                this.filters = filters;
                this.bindEvents();
              };
              /*remove checked boxes when click*/
              this.bindEvents = function() {
                this.filters.click(this.filtrBeseda);
                $('#none').click(this.removeAllFilters);
              };
              
    

              this.filtrBeseda = function() {
                _this.lectures.hide();
                var filtredLectures = _this.lectures;
                var filterAttributes = $('.filter-attributes'); 
                filterAttributes.each(function(){
                var selectedFilters = $(this).find('input:checked');
                if (selectedFilters.length) {
                  var selectedFiltersValues = [];
                  selectedFilters.each(function() {
                  var currentFilter = $(this);
                  selectedFiltersValues.push("[data-" + currentFilter.attr('name') + "='" + currentFilter.val() + "']");
                  });
                  filtredLectures = filtredLectures.filter(selectedFiltersValues.join(','));
                }
                });
                filtredLectures.show();
              };}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <div id='filters' class='seznamBesed'>

<br>
  <div class='filter-attributes'>
    <div class=" nazev-filtru pobocka">Pobočka</div>
     <label for='Vozovna'>Vozovna</label><input type='checkbox'  name='pobocka' id='Vozovna' value='Vozovna' />                    
     <label for='Kralikov'>Kralíkov</label><input type='checkbox'  name='pobocka' id='Kralikov' value='Kralikov'/>
  </div>

<br>
 <div class='filter-attributes'>
    <div class="nazev-filtru proKoho">Věková kategorie </div>            
        <label for='ms' >Mateřská škola</label><input type='checkbox' name='proKoho' id='ms'  value='ms'/>
         <label for='zs1' >První stupeň</label><input type='checkbox' name='proKoho' id='zs1' value='zs1'/>
         <label for='zs2' >Druhý stupeň</label><input type='checkbox' name='proKoho' id='zs2' value='zs2' />
  </div>

<br>
 <div class='filter-attributes'>
  <div class="nazev-filtru obor"> Témata</div>
<div>
   <label for='knihy'>Knihy </label><input type='checkbox' name='obor' id='knihy' value='knihy'/>
   <label for='eko'>Ekologie</label><input type='checkbox' name='obor' id='eko' value='eko' />
   <label for='media'>Mediální gramotnost</label><input type='checkbox' name='obor' id='media' value='media'/>
 </div>
                </div>

<br>

<div class="seznamBesed" id="seznamBesedId">

<h2> Vozovna </h2>
  
        <div class='beseda' data-pobocka='Vozovna' data-proKoho='zs1' data-obor='eko'> 
        <div class="nazev">Filter Vozovna zs1 eko</div>
         </div>
    <div class='beseda' data-pobocka='Vozovna' data-proKoho='ms' data-obor='knihy'> 
        <div class="nazev">Filter Vozovna ms knihy</div>
       
    </div>


    <h2> Kralíkov </h2>

    <div class='beseda' data-pobocka='Kralikov' data-proKoho='ms' data-obor='media'> 
        <div class="nazev">Filter Kralikov ms media</div>
    </div>

    <div class='beseda' data-pobocka='Kralikov' data-proKoho='zs2' data-obor='knihy'> 
        <div class="nazev">Filter Kralikov zs2 knihy</div>
    </div>    
    </div>
```

Comment: What tag `h2` are you talking about? This tag is not in the code. Not in the snippet, nor on the site you showed.

Comment: Now u will find h2 in snippet, I forgot to change it. Sorry for confusion. 
Somebody also checked my grammer, thank you.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: no, there will be h2 in snipet to understand my question. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: And you have 6 elements with the class data-pobocka?  2 of which are h2s?

Comment: You want to keep h2 visible?  Does this line change that?  _this.lectures.hide();  Maybe you need to test for length and put that line in a conditional if statement?

Comment: Hey, I tried to solve this trouble, gave it some time, worked again, but I didnt find any solution.. during time I changed my question little bit: so one more time to make my question clear - I would like to toggle "h2" -> ".hide" if there isnt visible answer after its filtered. Not to keep empty headers on the page.